# Haskell 2014.0.0: Two 'Could not deduce' errors occur when executing simple function

Tags: function, haskell

I want to program a function 'kans' (which calculates the chance of a repetition code of length n being correctly decoded) the following way:

```
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)

comb n r = ceiling (fac n / ((fac (n - r))*(fac r)))

kans 0 = 1
kans n = sum [ (comb (n+1) i) * 0.01^i * 0.99^(n+1-i) | i <- [0..(div n 2)]]
```

Now, calling 'kans 2' in GHCi gives the following error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHEES.jpg
The functions 'fac' and 'comb' function normally. I even get an error message when I call 'kans 0', which I defined seperately.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You could try specifying the type before writin the function, `kans :: (Num a) => a -> a`

Comment: Are `n` and `i` integrals or floating point?  You use them as either one interchangeably, which is not correct.

Comment: In the future, could you copy the text of the error message and paste it in the question? It makes it both easier to read and find by means of a search engine for those with the same error.

Comment: Are you on CodeWarrior (it seems so). If you are, this solution won't run in the desired time

Comment: Will do, AndrewC! And specifying the type gives the same error, only it gives it as soon as I load the file. I'm not on CodeWarrior as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages both contain telling parts of the form

```
Could not deduce [...]
    from the context (Integral a, Fractional a)
```

This says that you are trying to use a single type as both a member of the class `Integral` and as a member of the class `Fractional`.  There are no such types in Haskell: The standard numerical types all belong to exactly one of them.  And you are using operations that require one or the other:

- `/` is "floating point" or "field" division, and only works with `Fractional`.
- `div` is "integer division", and so works only with `Integral`.
- the *second* argument of `^` must be `Integral`.

What you probably should do is to decide exactly which of your variables and results are integers (and thus in the `Integral` class), and which are floating-point (and thus in the `Fractional` class.) Then use the `fromIntegral` function to convert from the former to the latter whenever necessary.  You will need to do this conversion in at least one of your functions.

On mathematical principle I recommend you do it in `kans`, and change `comb` to be purely integral by using `div` instead of `/`.

As @Mephy suggests, you probably should write type signatures for your functions, this helps make error messages clearer.  However `Num` won't be enough here.  For `kans` you can use either of

```
kans :: Integer -> Double
kans :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> b
```

The latter is more general, but the former is likely to be the two specific types you'll actually *use*.

Comment: Your answer is so much better than mine though

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a complete noob at figuring out Haskell's error messages, so I should probably start learning that.

Answer (score 4):

**short dirty answer:**

because both `fac` and `comb` always return Integers and only accept Integers, use this code:

```
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)


comb n r =fac n `div` ((fac (n - r))*(fac r))

kans 0 = 1
kans n = sum [ fromIntegral (comb (n+1) i) * 0.01^i * 0.99^(n+1-i) | i <- [0..(div n 2)]]
```

**actual explanation:**
looking at your error messages, GHC complains about ambiguity.

let's say you try to run this piece of code:

```
x = show (read "abc")
```

GHC will complain that it can't compute `read "abc"` because it doesn't have enough information to determine which definition of `read` to use (there are multiple definitions ; you might want to read about type classes, or maybe you already did. for example, one of  type `String -> Int` which parses Integers and one of type `String -> Float` etc.). this is called ambiguity, because the result type of `read "abc"` is ambiguous.

in Haskell, when using arithmetic operators (which like `read` usually have multiple definitions in the same way) there is ambiguity all the time, so when there is ambiguity GHC checks if the types `Integer` or `Float` can be plugged in without problems, and if they do, then it changes the types to them, resolving the ambiguity. otherwise, it complains about the ambiguity. this is called defaulting.
the problem with your code is that because of the use of `ceiling` and `/` the types require instances of `Fractional` and `RealFrac` while also requiring instances of `Integral` for the same type variables, but no type is instance of both at once, so GHC complains about ambiguity.
the way to fix this would be to notice that `comb` would only work on whole numbers, and that `(fac n / ((fac (n - r))*(fac r)))` is always a whole number. the `ceiling` is redundant.
then we should replace `/` in `comb`'s definition by `\`div`` to express that only whole numbers will be the output.

the last thing to do is to replace `comb (n+1) i` with `fromIntegral (comb (n+1) i)` (`fromIntegral` is a function which casts whole numbers to arbitrary types) because otherwise the types would mismach again - adding this allowes us to separate the type of `comb (n+1) i` (which is a whole number) from the type of `0.01^i` which is of course a floating-point number.

this solves all problems and results in the code I wrote above in the "short dirty answer" section.

Comment: That's precisely the code I tried to hint toward in my answer, except you forgot to actually include the `fromIntegral`. Always good to have more than one viewpoint though. Also you mean `Double` not `Float` - I have no idea why people keep bringing up the latter, it seems like a type you rarely want...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I say Float because of floating-point. Thanks for noticing the `fromIntegral`!